# Ler multiplas planílhas arquivo xlsx com PHP - PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Tenho um arquivo no formato xlsx com duas planilhas e preciso ler os dados em PHP para criar um script de importação no banco de dados.

Estou utilizando a biblioteca PhpSpreadsheet para ler os arquivos. Eu consigo fazer quando possui apenas uma planilha no documento, mas quando há outras não funciona.

**Documento teste.xlsx**

*Planilha1*
[image: Página 1 do arquivo]

*Planilha2*
[image: Página 2 do arquivo]

Código para submeter arquivo:
**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Importacao</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Upload do arquivo</h1>
 <form method="POST" action="processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Arquivo</label>
  <input type="file" name="arquivo"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código para ler os dados e exibir em uma tabela HTML:
**processa.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet; //classe responsável pela manipulação da planilha


function readData($arquivo){

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");

$spreadsheet = $reader->load($arquivo);

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

//Coluna - Retira o título(2)

echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="8" style="margin-left:100px;">';
foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator(2) as $row) {
    $cellInterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellInterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

    echo '<tr>';
    //Linha
    foreach ($cellInterator as $cell) {
        if(!is_null($cell)){
            $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            echo "<td> $value </td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
}

$dados = $_FILES['arquivo'];

var_dump($dados);


$route = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
readData($route);
//$route = 'spreadsheet1.xlsx';
if(!empty($route)){


}else{
    echo "null";
}


?>
```

**Relembrando q o código funciona para ler um arquivo com apenas uma planilha. O que eu preciso é que ele leia as outras planinhas presentes no mesmo aquivo (abaixo do editor calc com os nomes *Planilha1* e *Planilha2***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é na linha:

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

Dessa maneira tu está pegando apenas a planilha ativa e processando os dados, sem pegar as outras planilhas do documento.

Nos [docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/worksheets/) falam sobre as funções `$spreadsheet.getSheetCount()` e `$spreadsheet.getSheet()`.

Me parece que a solução do teu problema é pegar a quantidade de planilhas do documento usando `$spreadsheet.getSheetCount()` e acessar elas dentro de um `for` com o `$spreadsheet.getSheet()`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");

$spreadsheet = $reader->load($arquivo);
$sheet_count = $spreadsheet->getSheetCount();

for ($i=0 ; $i < $sheet_count ; $i++) {
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet($i);

    // processa os dados da planilh
}
```

Comment: Muito bom cara!! Funcionou aqui.
Porém surgiu um problema aqui ao submeter meu arquivo, parece que ele é muito grande. Aparece esse erro: 
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /var/www/dir/script/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 999

Comment: Esse é um problema([docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/faq/)) com a limitação de memória que o PHP impõe aos scripts. Ou tu vai ter que ir liberando memória após o uso, ou aumentar a memória disponível para o script.

Answer (score -2):

//<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

//Adicione no php ou outro valor para corrigir isto