# Como posso ler arquivos .xlsx com PHP ou JS?

Tags: php, javascript, microsoft-excel

Olá,
estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde preciso mostrar dados de uma planilha Excel que esta com formato .xlsx em uma página. Eu pesquisei e encontrei sobre o PHPExcel mas o mesmo foi descontinuado. Queria saber se existe alguma forma de ler as células e apenas apresentar o dado na tela.

Comment: Olá, utilize o [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) ou mesmo o PHPExcel descontinuado, pois dependendo do que você precisa fazer ele vai servir. Acredito que apenas com PHP você já consegue, não é necessário JS.

Comment: Essa pergunta já foi feita aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/326903/ler-multiplas-plan%C3%ADlhas-arquivo-xlsx-com-php-phpspreadsheet

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ler multiplas planílhas arquivo xlsx com PHP - PhpSpreadsheet](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/326903/ler-multiplas-plan%c3%adlhas-arquivo-xlsx-com-php-phpspreadsheet)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, para javascript eu utilizei a ferramenta do link abaixo:

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.